# Include forwarded path phoenix

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

When forwarding to another router, something like:

```
scope "/" do
  get page_controller, :index
  forward "/child", ChildWeb.Router
do
```

The `page_path(conn, :other)` inside the `ChildWeb` evaluates to

`"/other"`

As it was forwarded using the `"/child"` string, it would be great if `page_path` could actually be evaluated including a prefix of `"/child"`

What would be a nice way of handling this so that I can get the forwarded prefix and have the url be evaluated to `"/child/other"`?

Comment: This is very weird because it should generate "/child/other". Do you have a sample app that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Here is an example app which replicates the issue: https://github.com/shouston3/forwarded_path_umbrella. If you follow the quick start instructions we have a failing test, where I would have hoped the test to pass

Comment: When you are testing inside the child application, then it won't generate the path at all, since the path only exists when you mount it inside the parent application. However, if you want to make sure that the tests match, to avoid confusion, you can add `url: [path: "/child"]` to the configuration of your ChilbWeb.Endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @JoséValim. That's exactly what I was looking for